# jQuery event click in nested divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I got a page that loads content dynamically.

This is the resumed HTML code generated by **page_ONE.php**

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', "#contentarea_ONE a", function(ev) { 
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $('#contentarea_ONE').load($(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
    });
    });
</script>
<div id="contentarea_ONE">
</div>
</body>
```

I have the ALMOST SAME code for **page_TWO.php** and **page_THREE.php**, just changing ONE for TWO or THREE wherever it corresponds.

I have buttons in each page that permits me to load **page_TWO.php inside #contentarea_ONE**, and **page_THREE.php inside #contentarea_TWO**.

Firebug shows me this as the HTML in navigator memory:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', "#contentarea_ONE a", function(ev) { 
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $('#contentarea_ONE').load($(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
    });
    });
</script>
<div id="contentarea_ONE">

<div id="contentarea_TWO">

<div id="contentarea_THREE">

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Well, this is the problem: when I have the three pages loaded in that nested way, **when I click a link** like `<a href="xxx/yyy">` **inside div #contentarea_THREE**, although I would expect the content loads inside contentarea_THREE, the content **is loaded inside the div #contentarea_TWO**.

Why does that occur?

Comment: I don't think your javascript is loaded on the included files. Try replacing your on click event handler in page two with an alert and I suspect it's the function in page one that's called instead of page 2?

Comment: you should try with closest contentarea

Comment: "I have buttons in each page that permits me to load page_TWO.php inside #contentarea_ONE, and page_THREE.php inside #contentarea_TWO." Is that actually correct, or did you mean `page_TWO.php` goes in `#contentarea_TWO` and `page_THREE.php` goes in `#contentarea_THREE`?

Comment: It's like I write it... the page_TWO loads inside the div contentarea_ONE. Anyway, don't worry. The Jai's solutions resolved the  problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '[id^="contentarea_"] a', function(ev) { 
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
        $(this).closest('[id^="contentarea_"]').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

See first of all all your divs are starting with same id initials or i might say they have `contentarea_` in common. so try using attr selectors and when you are clicking the links inside this div then try finding out the closest div with same id initials `$(this).closest('[id^="contentarea_"]')` and perform the load.

Comment: You might want to consider explaining what that does and why it would help them. Generally code on its own isn't very educational.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes i was just out of my system when i posted it.